# LibreOffice Writer - how to include content of config files?

Tags: libreoffice

I'd like to insert some config files as sample in a document (in a TextBox if it is possible). Can I do it without breaking the lines which are longer than the TextBox with? 
I'd like to see a horizontal scroll in this case instead of splitting.

Comment: I don't want to use any plugins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Floating Frame**. Read the answer in [How to add a scrollable table in LibreOffice Impress?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53484/how-to-add-a-scrollable-table-in-libreoffice-impress) to see how.

Comment: Thanks, but actually it's not what I want.
I just like to copy the content of a config file, not the file as object.

Comment: @ZéHá if you get the file inserted as object, you can change the file extension to `.txt`, after that the frame will resemble text box. I admit this is not perfect, let's see the other answers...

Comment: Vlastimil Ovčáčík:   sorry, I can't explain in Englsh :(   I have no real text object, I just want to write a sample text in this box and when I inster an empty Floating Frame, I get a bit square in the center of the line which I can't resize as I need. I will try to share a screenshot if I could...

Comment: O.K., I've found a solution, but it isn't perfect... :)
These samples are on a remote machine, which I can access via ssh/PuTTy. I can't access them as a samba share. The only option is cat file's content to the terminal and copy by cut'n'paste to Windows. (remote machine=a router with openwrt, without X, so I can't run LibreOffice on that ;) )
I copy the text into a local textfile, which can use as object for the floating frame, and problem solved. :))

Comment: @ZéHá okay, my bad. It is ok to answer your own question and accept it, if you have solved it.

Comment: Vlastimil: offtopic, but how can you put "@" before the nick. When I tried to reply to you, "@" vanished every time :(

Comment: @ZéHá [that is intentional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099), StackExchange detects it is not necessary to address me via `@Vlastimil` and removes it, I would still get notified.